# Creating a Custom Live USB Lubuntu with Scripts

Tags: scripts, lubuntu, live-usb, email, aircrack-ng

Working on a project for a client, the deliverables are a lightweight Linux Distro (I'm using Lubuntu versus Puppy or Mint due to familiarity), is Live Bootable from a 8/16GB USB drive and upon startup runs a script that will automatically send emails/SMS messages to specified email addresses and phone numbers (not exactly sure how to do the phone numbers) and a few specific programs installed

So first, is this even possible? I've had servers where our SysAds made scripts that would send emails to whole distro lists when a server was rebooting or archiving - that was on RHEL/CentOS - I haven't played around with it in Lubuntu.

I've tried making a persistent drive in UNetBootin but it wouldn't save any changes, and I allocated more than enough space for the recommended install (4.6GB). I've read this tutorial: [Putting A Full Installation of Lubuntu on a USB Drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450354/putting-a-full-installation-of-lubuntu-on-a-usb-drive), and will try it once I get another CD/USB - unless there is a way to download the installer as a standalone, I have a full version of Lubuntu on 2 different production laptops.

IF I use that method I listed above, I assume I could do all the scripts, and download/delete the programs I needed and it would save? Or can I modify Lubuntu with the Ubuntu Customization Kit ([Create a customized Ubuntu Live USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339874/create-a-customized-ubuntu-live-usb)) and do all the work I needed from there THEN make a custom Live USB Install?

As far as the script to send emails/messages - I know I need Send Mail at least, any other sources online I can go to? I've seen tutorials for Arch and CentOS - but none from Lubuntu. The programs I need are the aircrack-ng suite, wireshark, TOR, Abiword and Sendmail then delete anything else - is that also doable on Lubuntu? I've only ever used those networking tools on Kali for work.

Sorry for the lengthy post, I'm a PM by trade - so I'm sure I got the wording on somethings totally FUBAR, thank you in advance.